# Get post_id on clicking a link in WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am clicking on the link define in the anchor tag and fetching the url. I want to pass this url in url_to_postid($_POST['url']) which returns me ID.

What I have done till far now is everything working except the ajax call on admin-ajax to pass url to fetch ID

Step 1 : Created a widget in widget() function

Step 2 : Calling get_prev_ajax_handler() function on click and want to get the 
             post ID of that link using url_to_postid($_POST['url']);

```
 function Reco_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Reco_Person' );
 }

 add_action( 'widgets_init', 'Reco_load_widget' );

 class Reco_Person extends WP_Widget {
       function __construct() {
          parent::__construct(
            'wpb_widget_per', 
             __('Reco Personalisation','wpb_widget_per_person'), 
             array( 'description' => __( 'Content widget', 'wpb_widget_per_person' ), ) 
          );
       }
       public function widget( $args, $instance ) { ?>
           <script>
             jQuery(function(){
                jQuery('a').click(function(){
                    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                    jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: ({
                        action: "get_prev_ajax_handler",
                        url: url
                    }),
                    success: function (response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
             });

             });
           </script>
       <?php }
       public function get_prev_ajax_handler() {
           return url_to_postid($_POST["url"]);
       }
 }
 add_action('wp_ajax_get_prev', 'get_prev_ajax_handler'); // add action for logged users
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_prev', 'get_prev_ajax_handler' );
```

But this hook is not working. Did I invoke add_action at wrong place with wrong parameter?

Comment: please properly format your question, and make sure it is actually readable and it is possible to understand it. in addition add all relevant code, and debugging effort you have done.

Answer (score 1):

the another way to get the `post_id` by clicking on the `link` is to add a `data-attribute` to the link. e.g; `data-post-id="'.get_the_ID().'"`

your html code should look like

```
<a href="#link" data-post-id="47">Link</a>
```

then in your js code above the ajax call

```
var post_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-post-id');
```

and pass this in your `data` object to the ajax call.

```
data: ({
     action: "get_prev_ajax_handler",
     url: url,
     post_id: post_id,
}),
```

now you can get the `post_id` with `$_POST['post_id']` or `print_r()` the `$_POST` `array()`

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` in JQuery and and hook action is not matching.
It should be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_prev_ajax_handler', 'get_prev_ajax_handler'); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_prev_ajax_handler', 'get_prev_ajax_handler' );
```

Also get `get_prev_ajax_handler` function outside `Reco_Person` class.